# Where is the python workspace path located in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I created a Python project using PyCharm (2019.3.3) in folder `F:\FolderA` then I realized I meant to create it in `F:\FolderB`. So I copied my project from `FolderA` to `FolderB`. Now when I try to install a package, PyCharm says:

```
Cannot start process, the working directory 'F:\Projects\FolderA\MyProject\venv\Scripts' does not exist
```

I come from `C#` background, and everything project related is saved in `.csproj` file. Does Python have a similar file where it writes project/workspace information? So I can point to the correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside /venv/scripts folder there are three "Activate" files. It holds the path to the old directory.

- Replace the old paths with new paths
- Restart PyCharm
- Install package

Here's a screenshot of the path to the files:
[image]